# How to get retrieve relevant calendar events through Google Calendar API?

Tags: powershell, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

I have come this far with my script, which is simply supposed to retrieve the entries for a particular calendar for a specific time period (i.e. exactly what I see in the calendar).

```
#Powershell

ls (join-path $Script:scriptpath .\GDataCmdLet-master\Binaries\*.dll) | % {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($_) 
}

$service=new-object Google.GData.Calendar.CalendarService('Test')
$cred = New-Object Google.GData.Client.GDataCredentials('joe@gmail.com', '1234')

$service.credentials=$cred

$eventquery=new-object Google.GData.Calendar.EventQuery
$eventquery.uri='http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/joe@gmail.com/private/full'
$eventquery.StartDate = (Get-Date -Date '2014-02-10')
$eventquery.EndDate = (get-date -date '2014-02-20')

$eventfeed=$service.query($eventquery)
```

The DLLs I got from https://github.com/robertj/GDataCmdLet

All events from the calendar have actually been removed (i.e. I don't see any in the webinterface), but I keep on getting these as a result.

Questions, an answer to either one would suffice:

1. Is there a flag in the results, which distinguishes deleted from non-deleted events?
2. Is there a way to retrieve only the non-deleted events in the first place? (the parameter ?showhidden=false on the query didn't help)

Thank you!

Sandro

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! The following seems to work, not sure exactly why tough

```
ls (join-path $Script:scriptpath .\GDataCmdLet-master\Binaries\*.dll) | % { 
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($_) 
}

$service=new-object Google.GData.Calendar.CalendarService('Test')
$cred = New-Object Google.GData.Client.GDataCredentials('joe@gmail.com', '1234')

$service.credentials=$cred

$eventquery=new-object Google.GData.Calendar.EventQuery
$eventquery.uri='http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/joe@gmail.com/private/basic'

#don't use StartDate and EndDate this way
#they just didn't have the expected effect
$eventquery.StartTime = (Get-Date -Date '2014-02-10')
$eventquery.EndTime = (get-date -date '2014-02-30')

#that does the trick to get the actual occurences, not just the events
#and it also removed the non-deleted ones
$eventquery.SingleEvents = $true

$eventfeed=$service.query($eventquery)
```

Now I don't know where to get the start and end times of the occurences from, but that is for another question to answer...